# ASP.Net MVC 4 - Manually adding values to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to ASP and MVC and am creating a basic application based on a tutorial.

The app is a form with three different phases :-

- phase 1 is a form requesting basic details
- phase 2 is a form for family information
- phase 3 is a form with some other details

My app consists of a database which contains fields for different timestamps :-

- phase1Timestamp
- phase2Timestamp
- phase3Timestamp

As the user completes each phase of the form, I want to push a value to the database representing these timestamps.

What I'm failing to understand is how to do this manually.

Let me show you an example of my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customerFirstname)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customerSurname)
}
```

Then, in my controller I simply have a method which automatically pushes this data from the form to the database:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Summary(Customer customer, int? someJargValue)
{
    try
    {  
        // At this point push the data to the database
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // At this point - what if I want to add additional data to the database
            // which is not present in the form? Is there a db.Customers.setfield or something?

            return RedirectToAction("DatabaseEntries", customer);
        }
    }
    catch (DataException dex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.\nError details: " + dex);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error occured when attempting to save changes: " + dex);
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

See my comment above the return statement in the above snippet of code. I want to manually add some data to one of the database fields which is not present in the form.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean like this? `customer.phase1Timestamp = DateTime.Now(); db.Customers.Add(customer)`;

Comment: Ah yes - cheers. So simple, not sure how I failed to understand this one!!!